# Type conversion

Tags: java, types

I have

```
private HashMap<Key<?>, Val<?>> myMap;
```

In this map under a specified `key<T>` is always `val<T>` (the same `T`). I want to make a function that uses this information and automatically gives me a value converted to given type. Is it possible? Something like this:

```
public class MyClass{
    private HashMap<Key<?>, Val<?>> myMap;
    public Val<T> getValue(Key<T> key) {
        return (Val<T>) myMap.get(key) 
    }
```

(Type `T` is not given in the class.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions to this:

1. Define the generic type on the method:

   ```
   public class MyClass{
       private HashMap<Key<?>, Val<?>> myMap;
       public <T> Val<T> getValue(Key<T> key){
           return (Val<T>) myMap.get(key) 
       }
   ```
2. Define the generic type on the class:

   ```
   public class MyClass<T> {
       private HashMap<Key<?>, Val<?>> myMap;
       public Val<T> getValue(Key<T> key) {
          return (Val<T>) myMap.get(key);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: (Actually, come to think of it -- option #2 doesn't even really make sense. If `<T>` could be specified in the class, then `myMap` would be declared as `HashMap<Key<T>, Val<T>>`. But the OP indicates that that's not possible, because the `T` will be different for different elements of `myMap`.)

Answer (score 0):

Your suggestion under "something like this" will work correctly. Just use it.

Comment: It does not work, since T can be only defined in the class. Here, T has to be defined each time you execute the function, not during the compilation time.

Comment: Have you tried it? I think it will, given the rules for generics.

Comment: I have. It has problems with T class. Cannot find symbol T.

Comment: I know exactly what you need to do! Where you declare your class, instead of just putting the name of the class like `public class Class` put `public class Class<T> extends HashTable`. Some typing mistake, but you can figure it out.

Comment: Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I have made a mistake in the code. It should be myMap.get instead of "this.get".